# C#, How to save array _result[X,4] to text file with ToolSave_Click

Tags: c#, arraylist, savefiledialog, .net-rtf-writer

I have finished my Windows application Tool, but I have ran into a last problem. I cannot save my array, or I just don't know how.

so my tool opens a very specific text file with text like this:

```
Dog 슈퍼 지방입니다.
cat 일요일에 빨간색입니다.
Elephant    적의 피로 위안을 찾는다.
Mouse   그의 백성의 죽음을 복수하기 위해 싸우십시오.
racoon  즉시 의료 지원이 필요합니다.
```

I then place this into an array called _result[X,4] The resulting array becomes format as such:

```
_result[0,0] = 0
_result[0,1] = Dog
_result[0,2] = 슈퍼 지방입니다.
_result[0,3] = *Translated Text input*
```

When I'm finished with the Tool, I wanted to save to a .txt format

My current script for saving within the ToolSave_Click is this:

```
private void ToolSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
            if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFile.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
                {
                    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < (lineCounter - 1); rowIndex++)
                    {
                        if (_result[rowIndex, 3] == "")
                        {
                            var line = _result[rowIndex, 1] + "\t" + _result[rowIndex, 2];
                            sw.Write(saveFile.FileName, line.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var line = _result[rowIndex, 1] + "\t" + _result[rowIndex, 3];
                            sw.Write(saveFile.FileName, line.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When I save, the save text file comes out like so:

```
C:\Users\etomb\Desktop\workfucker.txtC:\Users\etomb\Desktop\workfucker.txtC:\Users\etomb\Desktop\workfucker.txtC:\Users\etomb\Desktop\workfucker.txt
```

Why is this happening, and how can I correct this last problem I'm having?

Comment: Try `sw.Write(line);` the stream already knows what file to use and your line variable is already of type `string`, so no need to use `.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you including the file name on every write?  Just use:

```
    sw.Write(line);
```

If you want things on their own line use:

```
    sw.WriteLine(line);
```